# Spark Structured Streaming multiple queries with different trigger interval relay on common view

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

Suppose we have a structured streaming application, in which we have multiple sinks with different trigger intervals and relying on some common view. How will the common view be handled by Spark: automatically cached or processed multiple times?

Following is pseudo code

```scala
val ds = spark.readStream.format("kafka").load()

ds.select(udf1(a) as a, udf2(b) as b, udf3(c) as c)
  .withWatermark(c, "1 minute")
  .createTempView("t0") // how will this line be handled?

spark.sql("select max(a) from t0 group by window(c, '1 minute')")
     .writeStream.format("kafka")
     .trigger(ProcessingTime("1 minute")) //one minute
     .start()

spark.sql("select max(b) from t0 group by window(c, '1 minute')")
     .writeStream.format("kafka")
     .trigger(ProcessingTime("5 minutes"))
     .start()

spark.streams.awaitAnyTermination()
```

**UPDATE**

Will the watermark be handled independently? My guess is that the watermark is 
mantained separately in each `writeStream`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case, these two queries read from Kafka independently, data will be processed twice. When you call `Dataset.createTempView`, Spark just remember the name with the logical plan of the Dataset. Next time when you use the temp view, Spark just insert the logical plan, the behavior is just like you call methods on a Dataset. The concept of temp view in Spark is pretty similar to the database temp view

Comment: "in my case, two queries read from kafka independently", does there exist other cases? (I mean I can not find a way to have multiple sinks from the same source without having a temp view.)

Comment: I also update the question, will the watermark be maintained separately?

Comment: Maybe this is more clear? Each query creates its own Kafka source with the same parameters. And watermark is maintained separately